# Skipping aoc file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' doesn't support architecture '1386'

Tags: updates, 32-bit, archive, architecture

When installing updates, I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

That happens to me errors from repository's of ubuntu, system 76 winehq also for updates.

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
1386
```

I try to remove 1386 (I must have installed while updating and installing updates for ubuntu, wine or lutris)

```
$ dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

Does anyone have idea of how to remove or 'instill privileged' for access to read & write to system architecture.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386`

Comment: tried that and have been getting error.

Comment: Please run `ls /var/lib/dpkg`, paste the result here.

Comment: ```$ ls /var/lib/dpkg
alternatives  arch  arch-new  available  cmethopt  diversions  diversions-old  info  lock  lock-frontend  parts  statoverride  statoverride-old  status  status-old  triggers  updates```

Comment: Could you take a peek on `arch-new` ? Run `cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new`

Comment: ```$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new
cat: /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new: Is a directory```

Comment: Navigate it then, `ls /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new`.

Comment: how would I find that dir?

Comment: It is on `/var/lib/dpkg`, run `ls /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new` to list file inside of it.

Comment: there are no files atm

Comment: ```/var/lib/dpkg``` Is a directory ```ls /var/lib/dpkg/arch-new```  no contents if that dir